# Chromadb export to a huggingface hub dataset

Tags: huggingface-hub

I am trying to export a chromadb embeddings file created using hkunlp/instructor-large model. I can chromadb embeddings using llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin.
Is it possible to export the entire chromadb embeddings as a dataset to huggingface hub?

I tried using export to json with no success.

```
import chromadb
from chroma_datasets.utils import export_collection_to_json

client = chromadb.Client("DB") 

export_collection_to_json(client=client, 
                          collection_name="my_embeddings",
                          file_path="my_embeddings.json")
```

I get this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'export_collection_to_json' from 'chroma_datasets.utils' (/home/superuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chroma_datasets/utils.py)

```
import chromadb
from chroma_datasets.utils import export_collection_to_hf_dataset

client = chromadb.Client("./DB") # create a Client object from your chroma db path
export_collection_to_file(client=client, collection_name="langchain", file_path="./notes.json")
```

I get this error

```
  File "/home/superuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 175, in __init__
    if settings[key] is not None:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is this even possible to do? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I tried using export to json with no success.

```
import chromadb
from chroma_datasets.utils import export_collection_to_json

client = chromadb.Client("DB") 

export_collection_to_json(client=client, 
                          collection_name="my_embeddings",
                          file_path="my_embeddings.json")
```

I get this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'export_collection_to_json' from 'chroma_datasets.utils' (/home/superuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chroma_datasets/utils.py)

```
import chromadb
from chroma_datasets.utils import export_collection_to_hf_dataset

client = chromadb.Client("./DB") # create a Client object from your chroma db path
export_collection_to_file(client=client, collection_name="langchain", file_path="./notes.json")
```

I get this error

```
  File "/home/superuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 175, in __init__
    if settings[key] is not None:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```